# Why does BeautifulSoup (in Python script) only return some of the numbers from HTML

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

Due to some help I received from here, I was able to put together a Python script that allows me to pull numbers from HTML data. However, for some reason, not all of the numbers are being pulled even though I believe I am using the correct criteria in my findall() method. Here is what my script looks like:

```
search1 = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(data_payload, 'html.parser')
data = soup.findAll("td", {"class":"confluenceTd"})
for d in data:
    m = re.search('([0-9]+)',str(d.findAll(text=True)))
    if m:
        search1.append(m.group(0))

print search1
```

Here is a sample of HTML where the numbers ARE all pulled:

```
<td class="confluenceTd">
         <span>
          AutoRun
         </span>
        </td>
        <td class="confluenceTd">
         <span>
          1514444
         </span>
        </td>
        <td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">
         <span style="color: rgb(0,0,0);">
          61888758
         </span>
```

And in the sample below, only "63811289" is getting pulled but nothing else:

```
<td class="confluenceTd" colspan="1">
         <p>
          CSY: 63811289, 62277372, 612377891, 653856796
         </p>
         <p>
          RTY: 54346678
         </p>
         </td>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Why are you using a regexp to find the numbers instead of using BeautifulSoup to find the `<span>` that contains the number?

Comment: @Barmar to be honest, I'm not too familiar with Beautiful soup. Is there an easier way to do it?

Comment: The same way you found the `td` element, you can also find the `span` inside it.

Comment: `for span in d.findAll('span'):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.search` only returns the first match: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search

You can pull out all of the strings with [`re.finditer()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.finditer):

```
for i in re.finditer('([0-9]+)',str(d.findAll(text=True))):
    search1.append(i.group(0))
```